# ElasticSearch aggregations for facet search (mongoosastic)

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

I have been struggling with something lately. I am using Node.js with `mongoosastic` and ElasticSearch for search engine on the project I am working for.

The problem is that I need to do a facet filter for search (multiple categories, attributes and so on). I sorta got it working but performance is terrible. I researched the topic and it seems that ES aggregations are what I need.

Basically I need to get a list of available filters from ES so that front-end can render them properly.

This is part of the data I am working with (data is stored in MongoDB and is synced to ES using `mongoosastic` package):

```
{
  ...,
  data: {
    filters: [
      [
        {
          filterId: 123,
          valueId: 321,
          type: 'radio'
        },
        {
          filterId: 124,
          valueId: 322,
          type: 'select'
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          filterId: 123,
          valueId: 456,
          type: 'radio'
        },
        {
          filterId: 124,
          valueId: 457,
          type: 'select'
        }
      ],
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

My query currently can search for data just fine (using other fields not relevant here). What I am currently trying to do is to:

1. Get all available `filterIds` (in this example `123` and `124`) and all of their possible `valueIds`.

So in general - (apart from hits themselves) something like this (plus additional data like `type` or whatever):

```
{
  filters: [
    {
      filterId: 123,
      valueIds: [321, 456] 
    },
    {
      filterId: 124,
      valueIds: [456, 457]
    }
  ]
}
```

And so on. **Changing database schema is unfortunately not an option**.

edit: Additional information.

I can get the aggregations working for a field that is not inside arrays like so:

```
"aggregations": {
  "filters": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "data.name"
    }
  }
}
```

I have no idea how to do it for data that is inside the Array (at least in mongoDB, I guess it's getting flattened in the ES anyway).